# Cannot read more than 13 registers at once

Tags: python-3.x, modbus, serial-communication, pymodbus

This is my code:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='COM7', timeout=1,parity='N', 
baudrate=9600, unit=1)
status = client.connect()
print(status)
rr = client.read_holding_registers(2, 20, unit=1)
print(i, rr.registers)
```

And I get the following error:

```
print(i, rr.registers)
AttributeError: 'ModbusIOException' object has no attribute 'registers'
```

but I don't get any errors if read registers up to 13. I found by using this code:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='COM7', timeout=1,parity='N', 
baudrate=9600, unit=1)
status = client.connect()
print(status)
for i in range(1,20):
    rr = client.read_holding_registers(2, i, unit=1)
    print(i, rr.registers)
```

Output:

```
True
1 [0]
2 [0, 1]
3 [0, 1, 0]
4 [0, 1, 0, 2]
5 [0, 1, 0, 2, 0]
6 [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3]
7 [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0]
8 [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0]
9 [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0]
10 [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0]
11 [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
12 [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
13 [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
print(i, rr.registers)
AttributeError: 'ModbusIOException' object has no attribute 'registers'
```

Comment: Do you have more information about the server (slave)?

Comment: Maybe the slave doesn't have that register? Have you tried to access it directly, with a single register read? Or maybe the slave has a limited TX buffer and can't send more than 13 registers in the same package?

Comment: Hi @Tagli. Slave has that register. I can access it directly with a single register read.The slave doesn't have limit, because when I run my code in the raspberry pi (Raspbian OS) it executed successfully. But not in my PC (Windows 7).

Comment: Hi @Bosz. The slave is a software not a physical one.

Comment: You can try to increase the timeout on your client. Otherwise maybe you can post the code you are using for your slave.

Comment: Hi @Marcos G. I tried increasing the timeout but still doesn't work.

Comment: can you add the code you are using to define your slave?

Comment: I am using modbus rtu slave simulator software. I am not using any code for that. And I found that the code is working fine when I run it in Linux.

Comment: @Hari What will happen if you are using the length of reading from `20` to `125`?

Comment: Hi @Benyamin Jafari I am getting the same error.